# Relate person to multiple patients

Tags: hl7-fhir

I would like to have multiple patients related to a person (e.g. some children and their father/mother).
As the [RelatedPerson](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/relatedperson.html) has only a 1..1 cardinality, what's the best way to achieve that?

Making a resource for a parent and linking that to a RelatedPerson per patient/child resource seems inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Person resource to link multiple RelatedPersons together to indicate that they're the same human being.  RelatedPerson is intended to represent an actor who can act on behalf of the patient.  As such, it's essential that there be a link to exactly one Patient so you know on who's behalf they're acting.